# Flask request without port in url

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have an ubuntu EC2 server and want to run a flask server.  I want to hit the server using my domain name, api.example.com, without having to include the port number.  Right now, I can successfully access the server by doing api.example.com:5000/... but I can't figure out how to do api.example.com/....

Right now I'm just running the flask server directly, using python flask_server.py.

In flask_server.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=0.0.0.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`run` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.run) takes a *port* optional argument:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

You can do this for testing, but for production I highly recommend you read the [deployment options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/) section in the documentation which details ways to run flask with various front end WSGI servers.

If you need help understanding how all these components work together and how to set them up; [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mplewis/6076082) has a nice summary.

**Update:** The host param needs to be a string.

Comment: I've tried to set the port to 80, first I get permission denied.  When I run with sudo I get an on not being able to import the config module which doesn't make much sense.  I've tried nginx, apache, and mod_wsgi to no avail, can't get those to work.

Comment: Only root can bind to ports < 1024, and the reason its not working on sudo is probably due to path or Python environment issues. Not sure what you have tried; but simply - install nginx as root, to make sure its running on port 80 (the default). In this configuration your server will show the nginx page on `http://api.example.com/`; next [install uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Install.html) and then [follow this guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/#configuring-nginx).

Comment: ok I got the uwsgi to run but where do I place the nginx config and am I supposed to substitute your application with something? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/#configuring-nginx)? It shows you what to change. The configuration will be in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` if you are on a debian-based system (like ubuntu).

Comment: Ok I added it to the default file in sites-available, but get 502 Bad Gateway nginx 1.1.19

Comment: Buddy, you need to read the documentation - the reason you are getting bad gateway is because you need to run in the uwsgi process - that's what nginx will connect to; and the uwsgi process will run your flask code.

Comment: Yeah but are you reading the _right_ documentation and more importantly understanding what you are reading :) Post a (separate) question if something in the documentation is not clear to you.

Comment: In my case it runs like this:  * Running on https://localhost:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit). How can we make it like this?  * Running on https://localhost/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) (i.e. NO port in url)

Answer (score 2):

You need sudo privilege in order to use port 80.

```
sudo python3 app.py
```

That will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to use Flask server on port 80 is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Keep in mind that you might need super user privileges.

This kind of workaround wound be acceptable if your were still building your application.

If, as I understood, you plan to deploy your app in production then you'd need to do it properly.
Here you find step by step information for Ubuntu, as requested:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: This is incorrect. According to Flask documentation: "Defaults to 5000 or the port defined in the SERVER_NAME config variable if present."