# Flask 404 response from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am trying to get a simple AJAX request to be handled by Flask, but am having issues getting the request sent to the correct address.

I am using this simple route and function withing the app.py file to define how to handle a request to URL/HelloWorld:

```
@app.route('/HelloWorld', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def HelloWorldRouted():
    return "Hello World!"
```

I am using this jQuery function to attempt to send a request to URL/HelloWorld:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/HelloWorld",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log('Response:\t', response)
        }
    });
```

When I start the Flask server and send a request via my browser to URL:5000/HelloWorld, I can see the expected "Hello World" message, as well as a log of the request in the server output:

```
"GET /HelloWorld HTTP/1.1" 200
```

However, when I attempt to submit the request via that webpage, I get the following error in the console:

> POST URL/HelloWorld 404 (Not Found)

So my question is what do I need to do for the app to handle requests from URL/ instead of URL:5000/.
I am hosting the webpage and server on an AWS EC2 Amazon Linux instance if that matters at all.

Comment: In your route it should be `methods=['GET', 'POST']`. You just forgot the "s"

Comment: It's correct in my code, I just mistyped that here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627195/flask-request-without-port-in-url

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an example to send JSON data to Flask route and manipulate the response in template.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def show_index():
    return render_template("ajax_simple.html")

@app.route('/HelloWorld', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def HelloWorldRouted():
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            username = str(request.json['username'])
            return "Hello "+username+"!"
        except Exception as e:
            return "error: "+str(e)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`ajax_simple.html` template contains a jquery cdn:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="author" content="Ahmedur Rahman Shovon">
    <title>Ajax Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    user_data = JSON.stringify({"username": "shovon"});
    console.log(user_data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/HelloWorld",
        data: user_data,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        success: function(response)
        {
            $("#result").html(response);
        },
        error: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }        
    });
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

N.B.: I do not know about your cloud configuration. This is tested in local environment and should run in AWS also.

Answer (score 0):

I send all my ajax requests to my flask app using just the URL like so

```js
$.ajax({url: '/boxtimes/3/',});
```

you can even add a variable to pass through like this

```js
$.ajax({url: '/boxtimes/3/'+window.time3,});
```

Here is the function in flask if it helps has some extra stuff on my end but might give some clarity to how best to use it.

```py
@app.route("/boxtimes/<boxnumber>/<time>")
def timerbtns(boxnumber,time):
    global time3
    global time2
    global time1
    global timeset

    timeset = time
    if boxnumber == '3':
        time3 = timeset
    if boxnumber == '2':
        time2 = timeset
    if boxnumber == '1':
        time1 = timeset

    TemplateData = {
              'lc1'  : lc1,
              'lc2'  : lc2,
              'lc3'  : lc3,
              'lc4'  : lc4,
              'lc5'  : lc5,
              'lc6'  : lc6,
              'lc7'  : lc7,
              'lc8'  : lc8,
              'crnttime'  : crnttime,
              'timerstatus'  : timerstatus,
              'time1'  : time1,
              'time2'  : time2,
              'time3'  : time3,
    }

    return render_template('index.html', **TemplateData)
```